# Why are sequential UIView animations displayed concurrently?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation

I've written some code that moves some objects around on the screen in sequence. As each object finishes moving, the next starts.

The code is structured similarly to this:

Model:

```
moveObject
{
    // Code to move the object
    ...

    [delegate moved:self];
}
```

Delegate:

```
moved:(MyClass *)o
{
    UIView* v = [self viewForObject:o];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         [v setCenter: [model center]];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Move object
                         [model moveObject];
                     }];
}
```

Although the code seems to run okay, what happens on screen is that the animations are grouped into batches: a large number all happen at once, and then another group all begin.

If I place a breakpoint on the line `[model moveObject];` then it is hit several times with `finished` set to `true` without any of the animations being displayed on screen. Then, occasionally, `finished` will be set to `false`, and after I let debugging continue, all the animations will be carried out on-screen.

**Edit**:

However, if I change the code to occasionally *not* move an object when moveObject is called, but instead return without action, and wait the user to move an object, (and thus calling back into this code via the delegate's `moved:` selector), then the short strings of animations occur sequentially.

i.e. The problem appears to only occur when the code is in an *infinite* loop.

What's going wrong?

Comment: How is your `moveObject` method determining what model to move? Are you calling move object from somewhere else? Like a loop? Unrelated: can you even name an object "Object" without clashing to the internal classes och Objective C?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I've simplified the code quite a lot. Move object is called once from elsewhere, which starts off the chain of animations. (I don't think it matters how moveObject picks which model it moves.)